# How to make autosuggest field look like bootstrap input?

Tags: css, vue.js

How can I make the `<vue-autosuggest>` input look like the input from BootstrapVue (`<b-input>`)?

[image: Something like this]

Comment: probably you want to try `<vue-autosuggest class="form-control" />` if you already imported `bootstrap.css`.

Comment: @Sphinx I tried. It looks like default html input is inside bootstrap's one

Comment: Unfortunately, at least from looking at the demo on vue-autosuggest, the component wraps the input in a div. I believe the bootstrap CSS checks the element its attached to is of type "input" so this won't work @Sphinx

Comment: Take a lookat my answer @Fagam32 - you'll need to modify the component that ships with the vue-autosuggest package to include the class on the input

Comment: Updated my answer to expand upon what you need to do and why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the `form-control` class to `vue-autosuggest`'s inner `<input>`, as required for the Bootstrap `<input>` styles, you could use the [`inputProps`](https://github.com/darrenjennings/vue-autosuggest#inputPropsTable) prop (automatically applied to the `<input>`):

```html
<template>
  <vue-autosuggest :input-props="inputProps">
    ...
  </vue-autosuggest>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputProps: {
        class: 'form-control',
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Interestingly, that class used to be added by default in `vue-autosuggest` 1.x, but was [removed in 2.x](https://github.com/darrenjennings/vue-autosuggest/pull/85).

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-bootstrap-with-vueautosuggest-z06g6?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the the `<input>` tag of the `vue-autosuggest` component to include the class `form-control` from Vue-Bootstrap.

You will not be able to add this class directly to the component as the component wraps the input within a div block. Bootstrap CSS requires the the element to be of type `input` to properly match the CSS selectors.

If we look here https://github.com/darrenjennings/vue-autosuggest/blob/master/src/Autosuggest.vue at the component itself we see

```
<input
      :type="internal_inputProps.type"
      :value="internalValue"
      :autocomplete="internal_inputProps.autocomplete"
      :class="[isOpen ? `${componentAttrPrefix}__input--open` : '', internal_inputProps['class']]"
      v-bind="internal_inputProps"
      aria-autocomplete="list"
      :aria-activedescendant="isOpen && currentIndex !== null ? `${componentAttrPrefix}__results-item--${currentIndex}` : ''"
      :aria-controls="`${componentAttrIdAutosuggest}-${componentAttrPrefix}__results`"
      @input="inputHandler"
      @keydown="handleKeyStroke"
      v-on="listeners"
    >
```

This must be modified in your local version to include the bootstrap class.